# Objective-C: Why is my object being instantiated as __NSMallocBlock__?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I am running into a strange problem where I am trying to dynamically create a new instance of a `Class` property (`arrayClass`) that I have set and stored previously:

```
NSObject *instance = [[self.arrayClass alloc] init];
if ( ![instance isKindOfClass:self.arrayClass] )
    NSLog(@"Say what?!");
```

If I break and log `self.arrayClass`, it shows the proper class on the console (in this case, called `Store`), but when I attempt to create an instance of it dynamically and log the type of the instance, it is showing its class as `__NSMallocBlock__`.

What the heck is going on??

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it was a very silly mistake indeed. I had somehow created an empty `init` method in the class I was trying to instantiate, but had forgotten to implement it (or even return anything). Strangely, the compiler didn't complain about this.

Here's what the empty init method looked like:

```
- (instancetype)init {

}
```

Obviously since I'm not defining or returning `self`, the runtime doesn't get the object back from `init` that it expects. What it *does* get, oddly enough, comes back as this `__NSMallocBlock__` type, and trying to do pretty much anything to that object will result in a crash.

Comment: As presented -[init] does not explicitly return a value, it is returning garbage that randomly appeared in eax register or other place that is used by platform ABI to return a value. Here it seems to be a pointer to some block object (probably already released) just laying on heap. If you were more lucky, it would point to nowhere causing a segfault. Btw, how did you miss a warning?

Comment: @user3125367: maybe he had all warnings turned off :)

Comment: Honestly there are so many benign warnings in Obj-C I didn't notice it. Besides it only gave a "control reaches end of non-void function" warning. Imo this should really be a compile error.